# A MiniMax optimization with Expectation Operator

Tags: probability, optimization

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an $m\times n$ random matrix with Gaussian i.i.d entries with zero mean and unit variance. How we can think about the following optimization problem?
\begin{align}
\max_m\mathbb{E}_\mathbf{X}[\min_{\mathbf{A}}[\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{\mathrm{H}}]_{m,m}],
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{X}+(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\mathrm{H})\mathbf{A}$. Superscript $\mathrm{H}$ stands for conjugate transpose and $[.]_{m,m}$ shows the $m$-th diagonal entry.

Is there any algorithm for solving this optimization problem?

Comment: Can you please clarify how is $\mathbf{X}$ sampled? I mean what is the expectation over?

Comment: Thank you. It is Gaussian i.i.d.